# Gnucap: using Vsupply command in batch mode

Tags: simulation, software

I am simulating a circuit with Gnucap, and I'm automating several steps in a Makefile:

```
all:
        gnetlist power_switch_replacement.sch -s -g spice-sdb -o power_switch_replacement.net
        gnucap -i power_switch_replacement.gnucap
```

I've created `power_switch_replacement.sch` with Gschem.  The Makefile generates a net from that and opens it interactively in Gnucap, after running the commands in `power_switch_replacement.gnucap`:

```
get power_switch_replacement.net
model BC548 NPN
Vsupply +9v 0 9
list
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work.  The `get`, `model` and `list` commands run correctly but the `Vsupply` command fails:

```
Vsupply +9v 0 9 
^ ? what's this?
```

If I run the command manually (admittedly after a `build` directive) it works:

```
gnucap> build
>Vsupply +9v 0 9
>
gnucap> list
<snip>
C1 ( 1 2 )  100.u
Q1 ( 1 4 0 )  BC548 NA( 1.)
Q2 ( 3 2 0 )  BC548 NA( 1.)
R1 ( +9v 1 )  1.K
R2 ( +9v 2 )  1.K
R3 ( +9v 3 )  2.2K
R4 ( 4 3 )  2.2K
.model BC548 npn ( <snip> )                   
Vsupply ( +9v 0 )  DC  9.
```

Again I suspect I'm missing something fundamental about the way Gnucap works.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.